# ASMX Web Service Execution very slow

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I have a function that takes a byte[] as input and returns a string, when executed with a windows application takes 3 seconds to execute, while if the same function is executed within a webservice takes a very large amount of time to execute (more than 1 min).

Do I need to enable something?

Comment: How many bytes? How far apart is client and server? Have you timed the function itself in the asmx version, to see if it finishes in 3 seconds, but maybe the part afterwards takes time.

Comment: Wait, so you are saying that it literally just takes a byte[] and returns a string? How much processing is done in-between? Because 3 seconds local sounds like a lot of time as well. Can you show some code?

Comment: What type of bindings are you using?

Comment: hi, thanks all for your help! Here are some more details:
the byte[] is quite large (it represents an 800x600 photo). The problem is not with the transfer between client and server, but with the execution time on the client. The problem is with the execution time on the server .... for example a particular function when run under a windows app takes 1sec, while the same function under a webservice takes 10 secs

Comment: If you show us some code (ie the mysterious 'function') it might actually result in someone posting an answer.

Comment: My guess would be that extra time is going in serializing/ deserializing byte array and transmitting over wire.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing large amount binary data, I would suggest using WSE (Web Service Extensions) along with [MTOM encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx).